# jquery-mobile appropriate coding to implement touchstart

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

As per header which would be the best approach on an application that has multiple elements that have events bound?

Currently I am using a single implementation and switching based on the id of the element:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    switch e.target.id {
        case "x":
            ..do something...
            break;
        case "y":
            ..do something...
            break;
    }
});
```

Is this ok or an element by element approach would be better?

Answer (score 0):

I will agree to this solution, only if my developer will not forget parenthesis

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
    switch (e.target.id) {
        case "x":
            ..do something...
            break;
        case "y":
            ..do something...
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Rest part is OK, enjoy your script ;)